# Update password from table

Tags: php

So i have a project, that have a simple login system. There is a "users" table, that have "username" and "password" ecnrypted with SHA1.

And i have a simple form, that will change the password of the account that is logged in. But it is not working. Here is what i got:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['change']))
{
$nova_password = $_POST["nova_password"];
session_start(); 
$utilizador = $_SESSION['username'];
    if (empty($nova_password)) {
    $nopassword = '<span  class="error">Insira uma nova password!</span></br>';
    echo $nopassword;
    }
    if(!empty($nova_password))
    {
    $query = mysql_query("update users set password=SHA1('$nova_password') where username='$utilizador'");
    $sucesso = '<span  class="yes">Password Alterada com Sucesso!</span>';
    echo $sucesso;
    }
} //END IF
?>
```

When i go to the page, it says:"A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()".

This error appear before i click the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already started a session? Try removing `session_start();` under `$nova_password`

Edit: Do this

```
$query = mysql_query("update users set password=SHA1('$nova_password') where username='$utilizador'");

// Destroy session and send them to login form
session_destroy();
header("Location: http://yourdomain.com/login.php");
exit();
```

But If you'd like to echo a message first you could use `header( "refresh:seconds;url=wherever.php" );`. But yes make sure no headers have been sent yet. Else you could use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="seconds;url=url">`

Or you could turn on output buffering `ob_start()`. Then it don't matter.

Comment: Yes i removed that and its working. It wasnt working because i got a file that check if session is started on the top, because this page is protected for logged users. And after change password, can i do a session destroy and redirect to login form? I guess i cant user header since an echo had already been printed..

Comment: I will simply use echo and then session destroy. Because after when someone try to acess a protected page, it will send to login, because session has been destroyed :)

Answer (score 0):

Substitute session_start() line with this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))
    session_start();
```